# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, cmd

The below is a Java game where the computer randomly picks a number from 1 to 100 and you need to get that number. I want it to work on the Windows console because I need to show someone my project on another computer where there is no Eclipse (but if it only goes with Eclipse you should write down your answer as well, I will manage it somehow to get Eclipse there). It is already compiled but it doesn't work when I want to run it.

This is the error:

```
    Fehler: Hauptklasse Zahlraten konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
    Ursache: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ratespiel/Zahlraten (wrong name: Zahlraten)
```

So basically it says (in German) that the main class can't be found or be loaded. The reason is "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ratespiel/Zahlraten (wrong name: Zahlraten)"

Here is my code for the project:

```
    package ratespiel;

    import java.util.Random;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Zahlraten {
        private int zufallszahl;
        private int ratezahl;

        Zahlraten() {
        ratezahl = -1;
        }

        void setZufallszahl(int zahl) {
        zufallszahl = zahl;
        }

        int getZufallszahl() {
        return zufallszahl;
        }

        void setRatezahl(int zahl) {
        ratezahl = zahl;
        }

        int getRatezahl() {
        return ratezahl;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Zahlraten spiel = new Zahlraten();
        boolean geraten = false;
        int versuchzealer = 0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
               "Erraten Sie eine ganze Zahl aus dem Bereich von 1 bis 100!");
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        spiel.setZufallszahl(randomGenerator.nextInt(101));
        while (!geraten) {
            spiel.setRatezahl(Integer.parseInt(
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welche Zahl wird gesucht?")));
        versuchzealer++;
        if (spiel.getRatezahl() < spiel.getZufallszahl()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ihre Zahl ist zu klein!");
        } else {
            if (spiel.getRatezahl() > spiel.getZufallszahl()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ihre Zahl ist zu groß!");
            } else {
                geraten = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Glückwunsch! Sie haben die Zahl mit "
            + versuchzealer + " Versuchen erraten!"); 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm sorry that all the Text is written in German, if you need a translation just let me know.

Comment: What is the command you execute to start your program.  It could simply be that Zahlraten isn't found on  the classpath.

Comment: Poor title. Edit to be specific to your issue.

Comment: Pro-tip: _always_ use good titles anywhere on the internet. They are intended to be a helpful summary of the problem to assist current helpers and future readers - people will often downvote "I am stuck" or "help me" titles because it looks like the poster was not willing to make an effort to write a useful one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just compiled this code and it worked perfectly fine, It may be a issue when you are exporting it make sure you are exporting the file as a runnable JAR file, if you don't it wont export the necessary documentation defining where the main class is. in Eclipse you can do this by going to the file menu in the top left corner then click export which will bring up the dialogue bellow, then click runnable JAR.

[image]

Comment: Where can I do that ... I just do the .java after the name. I was told so to do that and in most cases it worked so please instruct me where and how I can do that

Comment: Okay so what you do click file at the top left of the screen, then click export, then click java, then Runnable JAR file then finish

Comment: In eclipse, the program you used to create the project on

Comment: So Ive done that to this point ... another question should I save it as an ANT script?

Comment: There is no need to save it as a ant script, no

Comment: Okay what is the new error? And do you get the error when trying to run it?

Comment: It is because I needed to Launch it and the only thing was another Project of mine so Ive done that and now it says java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and Kreisberechnung2.java:5

Comment: it is when I try to run

Comment: Make sure you are exporting and running the correct project, and if you use any arrays in you code make sure you don't go higher than the number in the list

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you forget the package

What you should use in the command line is:

```
javac ratespiel/Zahlraten.java
java ratespiel/Zahlraten
```

You must be in a directory **which contains** `ratespiel` folder and **not** the `Zahlraten` class. E.g. if you class is in `/source/raratespiel/Zahlraten.java` you should run commands from `/source`

Comment: This is it for sure, I need to add a comment about the current directory

Comment: This is the correct answer.  There was no need to build an archive.

Answer (score -1):

You need to export this as a JAR file. Jar files enable your Java code to essentially 'code one place, run anywhere', which is a benefit of using the Java programming language.

More information for how to do this in eclipse is [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm)

Comment: There is no such thing as "exporting as a JAR" in Java.  You may package or "archive" your application in a JAR, but that is not necessary to run it.

Comment: When you build your project, jar files are created based on this, so essentially...there is. Might not be necessary but it sorts his problem out.